# Arranging sequences in 2 combined arrays using Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to turn information on a picture of 13 colourful blocks into some texts. For example, I need to know how many yellow and blue blocks here, and their sequence.

"c:\target.jpg"

[image: "c:\target.jpg"]

"c:\blue.jpg"

[image: "c:\blue.jpg"]

"c:\yellow.jpg"

[image: "c:\yellow.jpg"]

What I have is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread("c:\\target.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('c:\\blue.jpg',0) 
# template = cv2.imread('c:\\blue.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.99
loc = np.where (res >= threshold)

# if print loc 
# (array([  3,  31,  59,  87, 115, 143, 171, 199, 227, 255, 283, 311, 339], dtype=int64), array([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], dtype=int64))


print str(loc[0] + loc[1])
```

When I run them separately, it gives results like these:

```
[ 13  41  69  97 125 153 181 209 237 265 293 321 349]
```

and

```
[ 10  38  66  94 122 150 178 206 234 262 290 318 346]
```

Well those are each 13 numbers but I don’t know how to handle them.

How can I turn them into texts like:

"blue, yellow, blue, yellow, blue, blue, yellow, yellow, blue, yellow, blue, yellow, blue, yellow".

Comment: Are the input images always a simple fixed stack like that, or do they sometimes have other patterns such as multiple columns, misalignment, rotation, etc.?

Comment: @John Zwinck, thanks for the comment. the block shapes are always simple and the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quite simple solution that just reads a stripe of pixels down the center:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(filename)

xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax = im.getbbox()
x = (xMin + xMax) / 2

colors = []
oldColor = None
for y in xrange(yMin, yMax):
    r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))

    if r > 240 and g > 240 and b > 240:
        newColor = 'white'
    elif g > 150 and b > 150:
        newColor = 'blue'
    elif r > 150 and g > 150:
        newColor = 'yellow'
    else:
        newColor = 'unknown'

    if newColor != oldColor:
        if newColor != 'white':
            colors.append(newColor)
        oldColor = newColor

print colors
```

It prints:

```
['blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue']
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it works! your way of thinking, to get the color of the stripe of pixels down the center is a good angel. I applied this way in other similar structure pictures and it produces good results too!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to convert from those numbers to string, I would do

```
bl=[ 13, 41, 69, 97,125,153,181,209,237,265,293,321,349]
yl=[ 10, 38, 66, 94,122,150,178,206,234,262,290,318,346]
x=sorted(bl+yl)
out=', '.join(['blue' if y in bl else 'yellow' for y in x])
print out
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. there are 13 colour blocks in the picture but it turns out 26 outputs and they are not reflecting the sequence.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood the problem, can you please tell me what is the output of `print loc`. Also, why are you converting to grayscale? Wouldn't it be better to work with full colors?

Comment: @MarkK, I think I found your problem, but I have problems with my OpenCv and cannot test it right now, can you please try this command `res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` instead of your matchTemplate, and then `print loc`

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. Impressive to see your zealism. I am not with a machine that can run OpenCv neither. Can we come back to this topic next Monday?

Comment: @MarkK Sure thing. Just to give you a heads up on what I think is happening. You are matching the template to a grey scale image, and it's matching all the rectangles. Then in loc you are getting the x and y coordinates of the matchings, but I don't know why are you adding them, that's why you get 13 values each time. You should try to match in full RGB colors and check only the y coordinate.

Comment: great! I tried the using "img_rgb" instead in the "res" line, but it gives error "error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:249: error: (-215) (img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F) && img.type() == templ.type() in function cv::matchTemplate"

Comment: please don't be discouraged because I choose John Zwinck's for the answer, even it's using another way. As the question is favorited, a solution could benefit many people if we can find out another solution.

Comment: That's because you are using imread in two different ways, one for the target and one for the template. `imread('file')` will open the file as rgb matrix, `imread('file', 0`)` will open it as greyscale. Try removing the 0 from the template imread

Comment: when removed the "0" from "template", it gives "ValueError: too many values to unpack".

Comment: Does it say that the error is with the `w, h = template.shape[:,:,-1]`,  because the shape of the template is different now

Comment: Try `print template.shape` so you can see the shape and which values you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98522/discussion-between-mark-k-and-noel-segura).