# Python, cv2, numpy to find images in an image

Tags: python, numpy

Similar to the question here, [Python, arranging sequences in 2 combined arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350053/python-arranging-sequences-in-2-combined-arrays/34350859#34350859), it’s interesting to have a solution, to find out how many different images and their sequences in a combination.

**The target image is:**

c:\four.jpg

[image]

By using “cv2” and “numpy”, what’s the way to have a result like:

```
['tooth fairy', 'santa and deer', 'santa', 'deer', 'tooth fairy', 'deer', 'santa and deer', 'santa', 'tooth fairy', 'santa']
```

The individuals are:

c:\tooth fairy.jpg
[image]

c:\santa and deer.jpg
[image]

c:\santa.jpg
[image]

c:\deer.jpg
[image]

thanks.

Comment: @Noel Segura , could you please share your expertise here?

Comment: Show some effort by your side as well

Comment: @ZdaR, thanks for the comment. I have the solution. but Noel Segura guided me so I would credit him in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting example. Sure I'll condensate what we got in the chat.

First open your images in rgb space with `imread`, then you can use `matchtemplate` and `numpy.where` to find the position, and from the y coordinate obtain the sequence, as

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread("four.jpg") 

template = cv2.imread('fairy.jpg') 
template1 = cv2.imread('sad.jpg')
template2 = cv2.imread('san.jpg')
template3 = cv2.imread('deer.jpg')

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
res1 = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template1,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
res2 = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template2,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 
res3 = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb,template3,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 

threshold = 0.99 

loc = np.where (res >= threshold) 
loc1 = np.where (res1 >= threshold) 
loc2 = np.where (res2 >= threshold)
loc3 = np.where (res3 >= threshold)

fairy = list(loc[0]) 
sandeer = list(loc1[0]) 
san = list(loc2[0]) 
deer = list(loc3[0]) 

x=sorted(fairy+sandeer+san+deer) 
out=', '.join(['tooth fairy' if y in fairy else 'santa and deer' if y in sandeer else 'santa' if y in san else 'deer' for y in x])

print out
```

Comment: marvellous! thanks for the guidance again, and the benefits to the learners!